# Derivation of Evolution Operator on finding Hu-Paz-Zhang (HPZ) Quantum Brownian Motion (QBM) Master Equation

Tags: quantum-mechanics, statistical-mechanics, stochastic-processes, brownian-motion

I am trying to understand this [paper](https://journals.aps.org/prd/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevD.45.2843) by Hu, Paz, and Zhang about exact master equation of QBM in general environment. In the paper they used influence functional method introduce by Feynman and Vernon to get HPZ master equation. I am a little bit lost on the derivation they used especially

1. To get equation (2.18) and (2.19), they mentioned expand the effective action in powers of *dt*, what does this mean. Explicit explanation is extremely helpful. (Page 8)
2. Equation (2.22) where does the potential ***V**(xf)* term came from ?

Comment: As I can see no free or pre-print version of the paper, please provide the relevant equations  (at least) in the question using [Mathjax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Comment: @StephenG I am sorry. I link different paper with the same derivation on its appendix [link](https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0703088). The equation I am talking about is first (A7) and (A8) and the second is (A11). Page (11).